# Absolute achievable minimum of GC with string concat in LUA?

Tags: string, lua, garbage-collection

**Runtime:** lua 5.1.x compiled under ARM64, no c-modules allowed

Example code, ready to run:
https://paste.gg/p/anonymous/08f364480a5f470e9da610ab565e11c0

I need to concat bunch of string per X ms in a loop. From my understanding, LUA supports *string interning*, which means that string literals are "cached" and not allocated each time. Therefore, only direct calls `tostring()` (or `..` sugar) will allocate. The rest of existing string-values will be passed by reference.

What I've done so far:

- eliminated all integer->string allocations (via LUT)
- although `tostring(bool)` does return interned string from cache, I eliminated that too
- created pseudo-stringbuilder via table that works via indicies (~16B each)
- "pre-resized" said table to avoid cost of associative addition and made it a global one so it is not collected and re-created each time
- used table.concat() for final big string concatenation

The final results still make me sad:

```
Allocated pre-concat: 2.486328125 KB
Allocated post-concat: 39.7451171875 KB
Total table meta bytes: 1544 B
Total tostring meta bytes: 273 B
```

Is there something I'm missing or am I at the limit of LUA here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to minimize the number of intermediate allocations of strings object in order to reduce the GC pressure and slow down GC hits. In this case, I suggest you to *limit yourself to 1 call* to `string.format` with the string your want to format:

- The string format can be declared globally so that it is  `interned` once.
- The `string.format` code can be read [here](https://www.lua.org/source/5.1/lstrlib.c.html#str_format). What we can see from this code is that the intermediate string transformations are done on the `C` stack with a buffer of `LUAL_BUFFERSIZE` bytes. This size is declared in `luaconf.h` and can be customized according to your needs. This approach should be the most efficient for your use-case as you just drop all the intermediate steps (table insertions, table.concat, etc).

```
local MY_STRING_FORMAT = [[My Very Big String
param-string-1 %d
param-string-2 %x
param-string-3 %f
param-string-4 %d
param-string-5 %d
]]

string.format(MY_STRING_FORMAT,
              Param1,
              Param2,
              Param3,
              Param4,
              Param5,
              etc...)
```

Comment: Yeah, I understand what `string.format()` is for is how to use it, sadly, it does not allow much for dynamic content because you have to supply all the data with no branching.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that the problem you mention is linked to the memory consumption of the function `CONTAINER.PopulateState`. I think your code is OK, but you are not measuring the correct things. I removed all the `collectgarbage` in order to gather them into a single part of the code:

```
print("Allocated PRE-concat:                " ..  tostring(collectgarbage("count")))

-- First time
CONTAINER.PopulateState()
print("Allocated POST-concat BEFORE-COLLECT:" ..  tostring(collectgarbage("count")))
collectgarbage("collect") 
print("Allocated POST-concat  AFTER-COLLECT:" ..  tostring(collectgarbage("count")))

-- One more try
CONTAINER.PopulateState()
print("Allocated POST-concat BEFORE-COLLECT:" ..  tostring(collectgarbage("count")))
collectgarbage("collect") 
print("Allocated POST-concat  AFTER-COLLECT:" ..  tostring(collectgarbage("count")))

-- One more try
CONTAINER.PopulateState()
print("Allocated POST-concat BEFORE-COLLECT:" ..  tostring(collectgarbage("count")))
collectgarbage("collect") 
print("Allocated POST-concat  AFTER-COLLECT:" ..  tostring(collectgarbage("count")))
```

The results are very different and make more sense:

```
Allocated PRE-concat:                48.70703125
Allocated POST-concat BEFORE-COLLECT:54.3232421875
Allocated POST-concat  AFTER-COLLECT:51.8515625
Allocated POST-concat BEFORE-COLLECT:54.5576171875
Allocated POST-concat  AFTER-COLLECT:51.8515625
Allocated POST-concat BEFORE-COLLECT:54.5576171875
Allocated POST-concat  AFTER-COLLECT:51.8515625
```

After the `initialization` of the program and before calling the `CONTAINER.PopulateState()`, the program already use 48.7 KB.

In the first call to `CONTAINER.PopulateState()`, there is a small addition of 3 kilobytes of memory which seems to be persistent: this memory does not seems to be freed in the program execution. This might be due to the bytecode compilation, caching or internal use.

But the following executions of `CONTAINER.PopulateState()` typically use 2.7 KB of memory and this memory is released each time. The program behavior seems to be pretty consistent: the execution of `CONTAINER.PopulateState()` will not make the program use more memory. Actually, the memory temporary used by the function `CONTAINER.PopulateState()` (2.7 KB) is negligible compared to the rest of the program (48 KB).

If you want to have a better control of what is happening, you could implement this part using `C` language and provide an interface to `Lua`.

Full code:

```
CONTAINER =
{
      Ver = "0.3",
      --- integer lookup for the DateTime
      timeLUT = {[0]="00",[1]="01",[2]="02",[3]="03",[4]="04",[5]="05",[6]="06",[7]="07",[8]="08",[9]="09"},
      strCACHE = { [100] = ""},
      SubStrA  = "Unknown",
      SubAPrst = "ASjdasda",
}
     
    
for i = 10,99,1 do
  CONTAINER.timeLUT[i] = tostring(i)
end
        
DataBlob = {
  vAng = { x = 1.0, y = 2.0, z = 3.0},
  vPos = { x = 2131.0, y = 42.0, z = -433.0},
    
  Composite =
  {
        VARIANT1 = { isFirst = true, isMiddle = false, isLast = true },
        VARIANT2 = { isIgnored = true},
        VARIANT3 = { isAccurate = false },
        VARIANT4 = { bEnabled = false },
        VARIANT5 = { isLocked = false, ImpactV = 1.8 },
        VARIANT6 = { troCoWal = true },
        VARIANT7 = { isBroCal = false }
  } 
} 
    
Global = {
  isLocked = function(x)return false end,
  GetTimeStamp = function(x)return math.random() + math.random(1, 99) end,
  GetLocalTimeStamp = function(x)return math.random() + math.random(1, 99) end,
  GetTotalPTime = function(x)return math.random() + math.random(1, 99) end,
  GetDataBlob = function(x)return DataBlob end,
  GetName = function(x)return "AThing" end
}
    
function CONTAINER.PopulateState()
 
    local gcInit = 0
    local gcLast = 0
    
  -- Cachig globals
    
  local floor, mod, tostring = math.floor, math.mod, tostring
  local G = Global
  local intCache = CONTAINER.timeLUT
  local strBuilder = CONTAINER.strCACHE
    
  -- Fetching & caching data
  local locDB, Name = G.GetDataBlob(), G.GetName()
  local ts = G.GetTimeStamp()
  local lag = math.random() + math.random(1, 2)
    
  -- Local helpers
  local function sBool(bool)
    return bool and "1" or "0"
  end
    
  local t = 0
    
  function cAppend(cTbl, ...)
    for i=0, arg.n do
      cTbl[#cTbl+1] = arg[i]
      t = t +1
    end
  end

  function cClear(cTbl)
    for _=0, #cTbl do
      cTbl[#cTbl] = nil
    end
  end
        
  -- Populating table
  cClear(strBuilder)
        
  if locDB ~= nil then
    locDB = G.GetDataBlob()
    local PC = locDB.Composite
    local tp = G.GetTotalPTime()
    local d, h, m, s = floor(tp/86400), floor(mod(tp, 86400)/3600), floor(mod(tp,3600)/60), floor(mod(tp,60))
    
    cAppend(strBuilder,  "[", Name, "]:\n",
            "Ang :",      "(", tostring(locDB.vAng.x),",",tostring(locDB.vAng.y),",",tostring(locDB.vAng.z), ")\n",
            "Pos :",      "(", tostring(locDB.vPos.x),",",tostring(locDB.vPos.y),",",tostring(locDB.vPos.z), ")\n",
            "isLocked: ", sBool(G.isLocked()),  "\n")
        
    if (locDB.Composite["VARIANT1"] ~= nil) then
      cAppend(strBuilder, "isFirst / isLast: ", sBool(PC.VARIANT1.isFirst)," / ",sBool(PC.VARIANT1.isLast), "\n",   
              "isMiddle: ",         sBool(PC.VARIANT1.isMiddle), "\n")
    end
    
    if (locDB.Composite["VARIANT2"] ~= nil) then
      cAppend(strBuilder, "isIgnored: ",  sBool(PC.VARIANT2.isIgnored),  "\n")
    end
    
    if (locDB.Composite["VARIANT4"] ~= nil) then
      cAppend(strBuilder, "bEnabled: ",   sBool(PC.VARIANT4.bEnabled),   "\n")
    end
    
    if (locDB.Composite["VARIANT3"] ~= nil) then
      cAppend(strBuilder, "isAccurate: ", sBool(PC.VARIANT3.isAccurate), "\n")
    end
    
    if (locDB.Composite["VARIANT5"] ~= nil) then
      cAppend(strBuilder, "isLocked: ",   sBool(PC.VARIANT5.isLocked),   "\n",
              "ImpactV: ",    tostring(PC.VARIANT5.ImpactV), "\n")
    end
    
    if (locDB.Composite["VARIANT6"]) then
      cAppend(strBuilder, "troCoWal: ",   sBool(PC.VARIANT6.troCoWal),   "\n")
    end
    
    if (locDB.Composite["VARIANT7"]) then
          cAppend(strBuilder, "isBroCal: ",   sBool(PC.VARIANT7.isBroCal),   "\n")
    end
    
    cAppend(strBuilder, "Time taken: ",intCache[d],":",intCache[h],":",intCache[m],":",intCache[s], "\n",
    
                        "TS: ",        tostring(ts),                   "\n",    
                        "local TS: ",  tostring(G.GetLocalTimeStamp()),"\n",    
                        "Lag: ",       string.format("%.5f", lag) , " ms\n",    
                        "Heap: ",      tostring(gcLast),             "KB\n")
    
 
    
    cAppend(strBuilder, "Alloc: ",     tostring(gcLast-gcInit),"KB"," (v", CONTAINER.Ver, ")","\n",
    
                        "Extra: ",     CONTAINER.SubStrA, "_", CONTAINER.SubAPrst,             "\n")    
  end
end
    
 
print("Allocated PRE-concat:                " ..  tostring(collectgarbage("count")))

-- First time
CONTAINER.PopulateState()
print("Allocated POST-concat BEFORE-COLLECT:" ..  tostring(collectgarbage("count")))
collectgarbage("collect") 
print("Allocated POST-concat  AFTER-COLLECT:" ..  tostring(collectgarbage("count")))

-- One more try
CONTAINER.PopulateState()
print("Allocated POST-concat BEFORE-COLLECT:" ..  tostring(collectgarbage("count")))
collectgarbage("collect") 
print("Allocated POST-concat  AFTER-COLLECT:" ..  tostring(collectgarbage("count")))

-- One more try
CONTAINER.PopulateState()
print("Allocated POST-concat BEFORE-COLLECT:" ..  tostring(collectgarbage("count")))
collectgarbage("collect") 
print("Allocated POST-concat  AFTER-COLLECT:" ..  tostring(collectgarbage("count")))
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the feedback. I might have expressed my question poorly, I understand the memory is released each time, that's what GC is for. I should have mentioned I guess that I'm looking for any other ways I possibly dont know to minimize GC pressure and slow down GC hits.

Comment: I misunderstood your question. I added another answer for clarity.